# EF Migration, new columns not showing after clicking "show table data"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using VS 2013, and have a MVC project using model-first and Entity Framework.

I'm following a tutorial and added two new columns to a table.

I ran the add-migration command, and then update-database command, which ran successfully.

I looked in the server explorer window and did a refresh and saw my 2 new columns when i expanded my table. However when i right-click -> show table data. I see that the columns have not appeared yet. Also, when viewing the script i notice it hasn't reflected my new columns.

Any clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved by closing out and restarting Visual Studio.

I'm not sure why, i hit refresh many times both in the server explorer window, and on the show data table tab, and well as closing and reopening the tab, and the show data tab would not reflect the new column until i restarted VS.